# merge sorting does not reach the last element

Tags: c, sorting, mergesort

If you pass the array size to the function as the index of the last element, then everything works as it should. But if you pass the size - 1, then the sorting does not reach the last element. What is the problem?

```
void merge(int *array, int start, int middle, int end)
{
    int i, j, k;
    int leftpoint = middle - start;
    int rightpoint = end - middle;

    if (leftpoint == 0 || rightpoint == 0)
        return;

    int leftArray[leftpoint];
    int rightArray[rightpoint];

    for (i = 0; i < leftpoint; i++) {
        leftArray[i] = array[start + i];
    }

    for (j = 0; j < rightpoint; j++) {
        rightArray[j] = array[middle + j];
    }

    i = 0;
    j = 0;

    for (k = start; k < end; k++) {
        if (j == rightpoint || (i < leftpoint && leftArray[i] <= rightArray[j])) {
            array[k] = leftArray[i];
            i++;
        } else {
            array[k] = rightArray[j];
            j++;
        }
    }
}

void mergeSort(int *arr, int start, int end)
{
    int middle;
    if (end - start > 1) {
        middle = start + (end - start) / 2;

        mergeSort(arr, start, middle);
        mergeSort(arr, middle, end);
        merge(arr, start, middle, end);
    }
}
```

Comment: There is no problem. If you are lying to `mergesort` about how big your array is, it will not work correctly. (This code uses inclusive lower bounds and exclusive upper bounds `[start, end)`, as is usual in C. Valid indices are `start <= index < end`. You could also design the function so that it takes the index of the right element instead, but then you must change the code.)

Answer (score 1):

Passing the index past the last element for `right` is idiomatic in C. Many books illustrate a different API, passing the index of the last element. While this would be consistent for `1` based arrays, it cannot reliably represent empty arrays and leads to confusing `+1` and `-1` adjustments. The posted code does not have this shortcoming and seems correct. It should be called this way:

```
int array[] = { ... };
int len = sizeof(array) / sizeof(*array);
mergeSort(array, 0, len);
```

If you observe that *merge sorting does not reach the last element*, you probably pass the index to the last element to the initial call instead of the number of elements.

Here are some remarks about your implementation:

- the index arguments should have type `size_t`.
- if `merge` is only called from `mergeSort`, itself called with consistent positive arguments `start` and `end` with `start <= end`, neither `leftpoint` nor `rightpoint` can be `0`, so the test `if (leftpoint == 0 || rightpoint == 0) return;` is redundant.
- saving the elements from `mid` to `right` is unnecessary as they cannot be overwritten before they are copied.
- using temporary arrays defined locally with automatic storage can cause a **stack overflow** for moderately large arrays.

Here is a modified version:

```
void merge(int *array, size_t start, size_t middle, size_t end) {
    int leftpoint = middle - start;
    int leftArray[leftpoint];

    for (size_t i = 0; i < leftpoint; i++) {
        leftArray[i] = array[start + i];
    }

    for (size_t i = 0, j = middle, k = start; i < leftpoint;) {
        if (j == end || (i < leftpoint && leftArray[i] <= array[j])) {
            array[k++] = leftArray[i++];
        } else {
            array[k++] = array[j++];
        }
    }
}

void mergeSort(int *arr, size_t start, size_t end) {
    if (end > start + 1) {
        size_t middle = start + (end - start) / 2;

        mergeSort(arr, start, middle);
        mergeSort(arr, middle, end);
        merge(arr, start, middle, end);
    }
}
```